# How To install Kali Linux Permanently on External Hard Disk

Tags: kali-linux

How can I install Kali Linux on external Hard Drive with permanent use? 
I googled it, but I did not get a clear idea for doing it.

Thank you

Comment: Compulsory link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install/ the installation is pretty much the same as with any other Linux distribution:

1. Download the installation image
2. Write the image to a flash drive:
   `dd if=kali-linux-2020.2-installer-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb`
3. Boot from flash drive and follow the installation instructions