# Can i Install an operating system in SSD?

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, ssd, kali-linux

I have only 250GB SSD in my laptop. There are already 2 OS, Windows and Ubuntu. Now I want to install kali Linux. Obviously I can't install it in this condition of my laptop. So I decided to Buy new SSd of 250 GB and then install kali linux in to that SSD. Now my question is "CAN I USE NEW SSD TO PLUG IN TO MY LAPTOP AND START USING KALI LINUX AND WHEN I PLUG IT OUT I CAN USE WINDOWS OPERATING SYSTEM." Can I do that? Please answer me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To install Kali Linux Permanently on External Hard Disk](https://superuser.com/questions/1554561/how-to-install-kali-linux-permanently-on-external-hard-disk)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using kali in a live usb. Installing on a external (presumably) usb ssd would not be a good idea because the slow transfer speeds. But you can install kali on the ssd, and configure your bios to boot from the ssd.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Cássio's answer, you need to flash your Kali Linux ISO to your external SSD (check Google if you don't know how to do this) and you then need to plug it in to your powered off computer. Turn your computer on and enter the BIOS (Check Google or your computer's manual if you are unsure of how to do this). Then find an option, usually called Boot Order, Primary Boot Option or something of the like. You need to then switch the first boot option to option reading the name of your drive, the model of your drive, Removable Drive, SSD or something of the like. Then save your changes and exit out of the BIOS, and go ahead and install your OS!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can boot your system from a USB device with kali linux intalled in it
, to do this your need to enter system BIOS and in boot options select boot from USB , make sure you don't remove the USB